# How can i check if $remote_addr IP is NOT in CIDR range in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am using `nginx latest web server`.
How can i check if the `$remote_addr` ip is NOT in specified `CIDR range` and `return appropriate error code`.

i would like to return specific error codes if IP is NOT in specific CIDR IP ranges.

**how can i do this for CIDR IP range** ? 
e.g.

- If remote_addr is not in 123.123.123.123/24 then return 444 code .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`geo`](http://nginx.org/r/geo) directive to specify IP address ranges.

Here's an example:

```
geo $block_these_turkeys {
    default         0;
    192.0.2.0/24    1;
    198.51.100.0/24 1;
    203.0.113.0/24  1;
    2001:db8::/32   1;
}
```

This must be in the `http` block, outside of any `server` block.

It sets the variable `$block_these_turkeys` to the given value, based on whether the IP address matches one of the listings.

Later, in the `server` block where you want to use it, do something like:

```
server {
    ....
    if ($block_these_turkeys) {
        return 444;
    }
    ....
}
```

By *reversing* the value, you can *allow* IP ranges instead.

```
geo $block_almost_everybody {
    default         1;
    192.0.2.0/24    0;
    198.51.100.0/24 0;
    203.0.113.0/24  0;
    2001:db8::/32   0;
}

server {
    ....
    if ($block_almost_everybody) {
        return 444;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Its working as expected , blocking everybody else with 444 and only allowing ips which are in CIDR range . i really appreciate it.

Comment: As of March 2023, the `geo` module is not available in Debian-based apt-managed repositories for _armhf_ (Raspberry Pi). The default Debian _bullseye_ apt does not have `libnginx-mod-http-geo`. The [nginx apt repository](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian) does not target _armhf_ architecture. (and manual compiles is a lot of work)